# Binary expression of a fraction

Tags: number-theory

> Find, with proof, the least positive integer $n$ having the following property: In the binary representation of $\frac 1n$, all the binary representations of $1, 2, \ldots, 1990$ (each consist of consecutive digits) appear after the decimal point.

I didn't see an easy way of going about this question since adding more numbers after the decimal point in also adds more numbers in. For example, suppose $\frac{1}{n} = 0.1011100$. We have to control the size of $\frac{1}{n}$ along with getting the most numbers with the least repeats. How should I go about solving this?

Comment: In what order do the binary representations of $1,2,...,1990$ appear after the decimal point?

Comment: Is it also possible that the binary representations for $1 (=1)$ and $2(=10)$ be contained, say  in the binary representation of $6 (= 110)$, so that some numbers can be ruled out?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг There could be representations inside a representation, so those aren't ruled out.

Comment: This seems much more like a programming problem than a strictly mathematically solvable problem. What is the origin of the problem?

Comment: @IanMiller It is from the 1990 International Mathematical Olympiad longlist: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h367410p2022400

Comment: @IanMiller What does the question mean by "each consist of consecutive digits"?

Comment: @user19405892: It means that $0.101$ contains $1,2$, and $5$, but you can't count the two ones as giving you $3$, because they're separated by the zero.

Comment: Can you add zeros in the binary representation? For example, $\frac{1}{2} = 0.1 = 0.10$, which contains binary representations of $1$ and $2$, and $\frac{1}{2} = 0.1000000$, which contains binary representations of $1,2,4,8,16,32$ and $64$?

Comment: Well, n being least means 1/n is largest.  So 1, 11,111, etc. ($2^n-1$) occur first.  Then all the 10, 110, (2^n-2) largest first, and so on.

Comment: $2^{10}<1990 < 2^{11};1990=11111000110$ so to make 1/n maximal we star representing with all 1s, that is 9 ones (1023), 8 ones (511) etc. So 1/n starts with 45 ones.  Of the remaining numbers 1 through 1990 we want the one starting with the most 1.  That'd be eight 1s and a 0.   Or $ 2^{10}-2$ or $1022$.  So we have 53 1s and a 0.  We want the most number of 1s to follow.  That'd be 7 1s then a 0 then a 1 (509).  Then comes 7 1s and then two zeros.  And so on.  We can figure out the formula.

Comment: After the first 45 1s, you have 1111111110:1111111101:1111111100: etc.  1022 - 995.  995 = 1111100011 we follow that with 1990 = 11111000110.  I think from there we do 1989 _1024. And then 994 to 1.  I guess actually we should try this with smaller cases like all reps from 1 to 13 first.

Comment: Okay, for 1...31 this is the largest 1/n such that all binaries are represented is as follows.  I've put | between each number from 1 to 31.  The pattern is easy to see but I'm having a hard time finding a way to index it:  1/n = .11111|1111|111|11|1|11110|11101|1110|11100|11011|1101|110|11010|11001|1100|11000|10111|1011|10110|101|10|10101|1010|10100|10011|1001|100|10010|10001|1000|10000.  It can probably be generalized to 1...1990.  But it's... tedious.

Comment: @fleablood $\frac{1}{37}=0.\overline{000001101110101100111110010001010011}$ contains all binary representations of the numbers from $1$ to $31$. Many of them overlap each other but they are all there.

Comment: Oh.  It never occured to me they could over lap.   The makes things **much** easier....  Except it doesn't as the largest binary decimal isn't nescessarily 1/n which I was too tired to even notice last night. Duh.  So... we need to analize what form 1/n take  Find the with all patterns of 0 and one for numbers 1 to 1990.  Shoot I have no idea... Do you know if 37 is the smallest such number for 1... 31?

Comment: @fleablood I exhaustive checked all values lower than 37 and none earlier contained the all binary representations from 1 to 31. From my playing I haven't exactly pinned down the relationship. It needs to be a prime bigger than $2^x-1$ but it isn't always the first one. For $1\cdots3→\frac{1}{5}$, for $1\cdots7→\frac{1}{11}$, for $1\cdots15→\frac{1}{19}$, for $1\cdots31→\frac{1}{37}$, for $1\cdots63→\frac{1}{67}$, for $1\cdots127→\frac{1}{131}$, for $1\cdots255→\frac{1}{269}$, for $1\cdots511→\frac{1}{523}$, for $1\cdots1023→\frac{1}{1061}$ and for $1\cdots2047→\frac{1}{2053}$.

Comment: I figure as if $1/x = .zzzzz$ then $1/2x = .0zzzzz$ so if $1/2x$ has all terms $1/x$ will too.  So the smallest will be odd.   I suppose there may as similar argument it needs to be prime but but I'm not seeing the reasoning for that.  With overlap if it contains all the terms from $2^n$ to $2^{n-1} - 1$ then it contains all the terms from $0$ to $2^n - 1$ as well so we only have to show it contains all (n+1) digit numbers starting with 1.  Maybe we can make some recursion argument.  Can $x < 2^n$ allow 1/x contain $2^n$?... we will need to allow for 1 ... m $m \ne 2^n -1$ eventually.

Comment: My thoughts towards primes is because the reciprocals of primes and powers of primes (most of them) have longer lengths of binary digits (compared to their size) before they recurr.

Comment: The length $x$ of binary digits of $\frac{1}{n}$ before they recurr is the smallest possible $2^x-1$ such that $n$ is a factor of $2^x-1$. This is why for $1\cdots15$ the answer is $19$ rather than $17$ as $17$ is a factor of $2^8-1=17\times15$ where as $2^{18}-1=19\times13797$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $n=2053$.

I have an answer but it is lacking lots of rigor. I have verified it by exhaustive search with Mathematica. What follows in my thoughts/reasoning. I welcome others to post further answers building upon and improving my working. Initially I explored this problem with a shorter range to find some patterns (e.g. only up to $15$).

Firstly we need a value of $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}$ in base $2$ is of sufficient length (before it terminates or recurrs) to include all possible representations. Prime values of $n$ hence have longer lengths and we do not need to consider composite numbers (except possible powers of primes). (Also primes of the form $2^n-1$ appear to be shorter than other nearby primes.)

We only need to consider the binary representations of values between $1024$ and $2047$ as values from $1$ to $1023$ will occur within twice their value. Even though we only want up to $1990$ we need to consider up until $2047$ as some lower values will not be present in the binary representations of $1024$ to $1990$ (such as $997=1994\div2$).

So I looked for the first prime after $2048$ which is $2053$.

Using a computer I found that the binary $\frac{1}{2053}$ is ($2052$ recurring digits):

```
0.000000000001111111101100000011000111100000110100110111101111010010100111000101111001000101000101001101001011111100001000100110101001111101011100011001100100000000010111111100010000100101011010001001111010011100110111011111010101000110101100111100111110011110001111010001100111001111110111100001010100110010110000000100011111010011000111000000111001110110111101011010011001110111111101010000011011011011101101101010110111010011010110111110011010001111111001100001000000110101110111100101010100001010110110010011100000111100110110011111011111000101001001001100100100000010010111101000010011101100111010111110110010001100001010000110011010111111110010000010001011101010001011011010001101111001110100111101101110010110110000011100011011100011101100011011000011110001011010010001111001001101000011111101011000011010001011111010001000111010100110110101111011100100101100010001000101010101001010101100010101000100101101010000111011010110101110011100101111100000100100111010001110111001101010111111010010000111001010111000010011001100111111111110000000010011111100111000011111001011001000010000101101011000111010000110111010111010110010110100000011110111011001010110000010100011100110011011111111101000000011101111011010100101110110000101100011001000100000101010111001010011000011000001100001110000101110011000110000001000011110101011001101001111111011100000101100111000111111000110001001000010100101100110001000000010101111100100100100010010010101001000101100101001000001100101110000000110011110111111001010001000011010101011110101001001101100011111000011001001100000100000111010110110110011011011111101101000010111101100010011000101000001001101110011110101111001100101000000001101111101110100010101110100100101110010000110001011000010010001101001001111100011100100011100010011100100111100001110100101101110000110110010111100000010100111100101110100000101110111000101011001001010000100011011010011101110111010101010110101010011101010111011010010101111000100101001010001100011010000011111011011000101110001000110010101000000101101111000110101000111101100110011
```

I then calculated all substrings of digits up to length $11$ to see if all digits were covered. Conveniently they were.

I then went back and exhaustively searched all values up to $2053$ and didn't find a lower value for $n$.

Here is my Mathematica code for exhaustively searching up to $2053$ if anyone wants to run it/check it/improve it/build upon it.

```
Select[Table[{x,Length[Complement[Range[1990],Select[Map[FromDigits[#,2]&,Flatten[With[{a=RealDigits[1/x,2][[1]][[1]]},Table[a[[i;;i+b]],{b,0,10},{i,1,Length[a]-b}]],1]],1<=#<=1990&]]]},{x,1,2053}],#[[2]]==0&]
```

Comment: ...you have found the solution to an IMO-grade question. By brute force. I think this is the reason why it didn't get into the IMO itself: it would be unlikely for students to sit down with only pen and paper and make a solution in 3.5 hours.

Comment: Yeh as stated I'm more than happy for someone to add some proper mathematics to this. I just put the answer there to potentially assist others. I got as far as guessing the answer was 2053 with some basic mathematics but had no idea how to prove/confirm it hence the brute force.